# Как по нажатию на radio в таблице загрузить в строке text-angular редактор и присвоить ему определенную модель

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Сейчас в каждой записи есть редактор и в первом столбце radio, как можно загружать редактор только в ту строку в которой radio true, на jquery  понимаю как сделать, а на angular,  что то не соображу пока. 
Первая мысль сделать еще одну директиву которая подтянет в шаблоне редактор. 
Может быть ваши варианты будут лучше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если редактор это не директива, то надо либо обернуть в директиву и передавать ей параметры, либо обернуть в скрытый div и привязать модель напрямую. Код бы посмотреть. Хоть что-нибудь.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov это директива, http://textangular.com/
Вот ссылка на github https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular
Задача в том чтобы когда воспользовался редактором память очищалась, и подгружался новый редактор, хотя у меня уже мысль сделать редактирование материала на отдельной странице, туда заходишь и в модель той страницы подгружается материал, тогда не будет мороки с несколькими редакторами на 1-й странице. Хотя такой вариант тоже интересный, когда по radio  в нужной строке грузится редактор